# cygwin in conemu captures keybinds

Tags: windows, cygwin, key-bindings, conemu

I have setup cygwin in conemu and it seems that the keybinds i have setup for conemu to change tabs (alt-1, alt-2, etc) are not passed through to conemu when cygwin is active.
Instead, they are captured by cygwin window and im seeing something like this in the window

```
(arg: 123)
```

which is what i would expect from a cygwin terminal, if i would press alt-1, alt-2 and alt-3.
[Here](http://postimg.org/image/tprjgd8e5/full/) is a sample gif that demonstrates the issue (just to make my problem clear).

Is there a way to tell conemu to listen to keybinds before forwarding them to cygwin ? Or a way to tell cygwin to ignore certain keybinds and forward them back to conemu ? (im not sure about the architecture of cygwin/conemu).

Comment: Was it you who asked me the same question on twitter?

Comment: Yes it is. I thought i ask here as well in case anyone had any tweaks i could apply.

Comment: All tweaks and solutions are described in wiki.

Comment: Except the ones that are not there. I went through the wiki, didnt find anything related to my problem and i thought i'd ask here in case someone had the same issue im facing.

Answer (score 2):

But I believe it's all there

> One more note about hotkeys. When you are running ChildGui, all keypressed must be passed to that application. That's why most of ConEmu hotkeys will be inaccessible. With exception of hotkeys types ‘Global’, ‘Local’ and hotkeys with ‘Win’ modifier, if option ‘Install keyboard hooks’ is enabled.

And there is Win+Z (default) hotkey.

[image: Switch focus between ConEmu and ChildGui application]

At last I do not understand why do you want to use mintty instead of simple bash...

Comment: Thanks, that switch focus was what i needed. Unfortunately for various reasons im stuck with mintty instead of just running a simple bash shell. Cheers for the help.

Comment: Win+1, Win+2 work as tab keybinds even with cygwin, mintty, etc

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the post [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551706/cygwin-in-conemu-captures-keybinds/27592781#27592781) i managed to solve my issue.

I used a function in Autohotkey that is active when im in conemu and it sends the combination {win+z, Alt+1} when i press Alt+1.

This way im switching focus+switching window in one key press.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class VirtualConsoleClass
{
    !1::
    {
        Send #z ;switch focus
        Send !1 ;change window
        return
    }
}
```